# When Button inside the recycler is clicked, another button responses

Tags: android, firebase, android-recyclerview

I'm trying program an absence register using firedatabase and recycler view, and the way is if absence button has clicked, it will be hidden and show only present button and also the presence button.
The problem is that when I clicked item, another item is clicked also but the second without click action (it doesn't send information to firebase only the first one.)

My recycler view holder

```
       public KViewHolder(View itemView) {
                super(itemView);
                mView=itemView;
            test = (TextView)mView.findViewById(R.id.test);
            MonthYear = new SimpleDateFormat("MM-yyyy");
            fullDate = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
            date = new Date();
            BUprestent= (Button)mView.findViewById(R.id.BPresent);
            BUabsents = (Button)mView.findViewById(R.id.BAbsent);

            BUprestent.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    //    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
                    FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("presents").child("kachaf").child(MonthYear.format(date)).child(fullDate.format(date)).child(Id).removeValue();

                    mAbsntDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("presents").child("kachaf").child(MonthYear.format(date)).child(fullDate.format(date)).child(Id);
                    mAbsntDatabase.child("uid").setValue(Id);
                    mAbsntDatabase.child("name").setValue(Name);
                    mAbsntDatabase.child("dayOfBirth").setValue(DayOfBirth);
                    mAbsntDatabase.child("wihda").setValue("kachaf");
                    mAbsntDatabase.child("excused").setValue("false");

                    mAbsntDatabase.child("excuse").setValue("/");
                    mAbsntDatabase.child("month").setValue(MonthYear.format(date));
                    mAbsntDatabase.child("date").setValue(fullDate.format(date));

                    BUprestent.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    BUabsents.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    //int pp2 = Postion+1;
                     recyclerView.scrollToPosition(Postion +1);

                }

            });
            BUabsents.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("absents").child("kachaf").child(MonthYear.format(date)).child(fullDate.format(date)).child(Id).removeValue();

                    mAbsntDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("absents").child("kachaf").child(MonthYear.format(date)).child(fullDate.format(date)).child(Id);
                    mAbsntDatabase.child("uid").setValue(Id);
                    mAbsntDatabase.child("name").setValue(Name);
                    mAbsntDatabase.child("dayOfBirth").setValue(DayOfBirth);
                    mAbsntDatabase.child("wihda").setValue("kachaf");
                    mAbsntDatabase.child("excused").setValue("false");
                    mAbsntDatabase.child("excuse").setValue("/");
                    mAbsntDatabase.child("month").setValue(MonthYear.format(date));
                    mAbsntDatabase.child("date").setValue(fullDate.format(date));

                    BUabsents.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    BUprestent.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    //int pp2 = Postion+1;
                    recyclerView.scrollToPosition(Postion +1);
                }
            });
}

    private void nextPostion(int postion) {
        Postion = postion;

    }
    public void setName(String name){
        TextView tvName = (TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.chible_b_name);
        tvName.setText(name);
        Name = name;
    }
    public void setId(String id){
        Id = id;
    }
    public void setDOB(String DOB){
        TextView tvDOB = (TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.chible_b_DOB);
        tvDOB.setText(DOB);
        DayOfBirth = DOB;
    }
    public void setReidence(String residence){
        TextView tvDOB = (TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.chibble_b_residence);
        tvDOB.setText(residence);
    }
    public void setImage(Context ctx, String image){
        CircleImageView img = (CircleImageView) mView.findViewById(R.id.chible_b_image);
        Picasso.with(ctx).load(image).noFade().into(img);
    }
}
```

Item XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_marginLeft="7dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="7dp"
    android:background="@drawable/contitmlayoutshape"
    android:clickable="false"

    >


<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/itm_brws_achbel_id"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="5dp"

    android:background="@drawable/itmlayoutshape"
    android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:focusable="true"
    >
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        >
    <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:id="@+id/chible_b_image"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"        />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        >
        <TextView
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="5dp"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:text="chible name"
        android:id="@+id/chible_b_name"

        />

        <TextView
            android:gravity="center"
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:text="chible date of birth"
            android:id="@+id/chible_b_DOB"

            />
        <TextView
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textStyle="bold"

            android:text=" chible residence "
            android:id="@+id/chibble_b_residence"

            />
        <TextView
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textStyle="bold"

            android:text=" chible residence "
            android:id="@+id/test"

            />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        >


            <Button
                android:visibility="visible"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="#ef8585"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="38dp"
                android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_clear_black_24dp"
                android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:textSize="12dp"
                android:text="absent"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:id="@+id/BAbsent"



                />

            <Button
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:visibility="visible"

                android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                android:background="#aaf4a7"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="38dp"
                android:drawableRight="@drawable/ic_done_black_24dp"
                android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:textSize="12dp"
                android:id="@+id/BPresent"
                android:text="present"
                android:textStyle="bold"

                />


    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Firebase recyceler adapter

```
 final FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<model_kechaf,KViewHolder> firebaseRecyclerAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<model_kechaf, KViewHolder>(
                model_kechaf.class,
                R.layout.itm,
                KViewHolder.class,mDatabase

        ) {
            @Override
            protected void populateViewHolder(final KViewHolder viewHolder, model_kechaf model, final int position) {

                viewHolder.setName(model.getName());
                viewHolder.setDOB(model.getDayOfBirth().toString());
                viewHolder.setReidence(model.getResidence());
                viewHolder.setImage(getApplicationContext(),model.getPhoto());
                viewHolder.nextPostion(position);
                viewHolder.setId(model.getId());
 }

        };
```

[image: here is a issue GIF]

Answer (score 0):

as what i understand .. you have to call setVisibility on absence/present buttons for each onBindView()

```
public void onBindView(){
 // here you have to check if the item[position]. is marked as absent ? show present 
  button else show absent button 

// in another words you have to **reset** the view state for each onBindView calling .. based on user interactions.
  u have to cache for each cell what the action does the user take with it.
}
```

Comment: i didn't understand ,could you explain more ?